# Can F# interactive help me find the exported types of a TypeProvider?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I've followed a [tutorial](http://blog.mavnn.co.uk/type-providers-from-the-ground-up/) only part 1. Although I was able to get the first half working in F# interactive. I'd really like to get the simple json provider types.

I'm doing right-click on the assembly, send output to F# interactive, then `open BTypeProvider.TypeProvider.Provided;;` which works fine. also the first (`MyType`) type is still generating just fine. But as the sample tutorial doesn't seem to use a namespace or an assembly in the call to `let inputs = ProvidedTypeDefinition("Inputs", Some typeof<obj>)` I can't seem to find any of the generated types from the 2nd half of the first part of the tutorial.

I'd love to figure out how to reflect on the exported types to find them. [Here's the code I'm running](https://github.com/ImaginaryDevelopment/FSharpTypeProviders).

Comment: It seems it may be unclear without following the links, I'm writing my own type provider, not consuming one that's already written.

Answer (score 2):

Several points that might be of help!

A full working copy of the code from the tutorial can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mavnn/Mavnn.Blog.TypeProvider) as mentioned in the tutorial. What is rather unclear is that the code as it stands tries to [load a json file from a hard coded location](https://github.com/mavnn/Mavnn.Blog.TypeProvider/blob/master/Mavnn.Blog.TypeProvider/Library1.fs#L36) and so not much will happen unless you put a JSON file with content similar to what's shown in the blog post into that location. I'll try to get the tutorial updated to make that clearer soon.

The namespace the types are exported to [is set in the provider](https://github.com/mavnn/Mavnn.Blog.TypeProvider/blob/master/Mavnn.Blog.TypeProvider/Library1.fs#L58), in this case to "`Mavnn.Blog.TypeProvider.Provided`".

Hopefully this will allow you to get the example provider working in FSI successfully - if you still have issues I would recommend attempting it in Visual Studio as there might be an assembly loading issue in trying to load `NewtonSoft.Json`.

On your last point about reflecting over the types, I'm afraid you're slightly out of luck. Most type providers, including the one in the tutorial, produce "erased" types; these types are available to referencing F# projects during the compilation process, but are not available at runtime for reflection or to other CLR languages. If either of these properties are important to you, you will need to do some research into generative type providers, that actually create "real" .net objects. I understand there are some performance implications if you are generating large type systems though.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had already copied your json file into my project, and have now tried opening a second instance of visual studio to reference it. However I get an error `Error 1 The type provider 'BTypeProvider.TypeProvider+JsonProvider' reported an error: The type provider constructor has thrown an exception: container type for 'BTypeProvider.TypeProvider.Provided.Inputs' was already set to 'BTypeProvider.TypeProvider.Provided.Simple' C:\projects\FSharpTypeProviders\BTypeProvider.Tester\Program.fs 1 1 BTypeProvider.Tester
`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible what you want.
I would usually compile once inside the main editor window.
This gets Intellisense working in the main window.
Then you can use "Execute in Interactive" from the main window to run what you want.
This is not exactly what you want, but I think it should help you.

Comment: *compile once inside the main editor window*, you mean compile the assembly in Visual Studio? *This gets Intellisense working in the main window.* - I was pretty sure you get zero intellisense against type provider provided types inside the assembly that defines the type provider. Is that correct?  *Execute in interactive* would seem to only be relevant if the other two are different than I understand them.